# Height set to 100% yet page not rendering properly

Tags: css

Here's a link to my page: http://mobile.sheridanc.on.ca/~vecanski/

The problem that I am having is that height is set to 100% and yet i can still scroll down and see the light blue, even though there is nothing on the page except floating bubbles.  Does anyone knows as to why I am able to scroll down?  Also I have a gradient effect, here is the code:

```
  background: #4094d1; /* Old browsers */
  background: #4a97ce; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4a97ce 0%, #2687cc 22%, #1080cc 48%, #0c0c02 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4a97ce), color-stop(22%,#2687cc), color-stop(48%,#1080cc), color-stop(99%,#0c0c02)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4a97ce 0%,#2687cc 22%,#1080cc 48%,#0c0c02 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4a97ce 0%,#2687cc 22%,#1080cc 48%,#0c0c02 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4a97ce 0%,#2687cc 22%,#1080cc 48%,#0c0c02 99%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4a97ce 0%,#2687cc 22%,#1080cc 48%,#0c0c02 99%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4a97ce', endColorstr='#0c0c02',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

What I don't understand is why does the gradient not go all the way, even if it is scrollable, why does it restart at the end of the page?

So 2 questions really:

1. How do I remove the scroll-able part of the page?
2. If I were to leave the scroll-able part of the page in, how do I force the gradient to extend to the very end and not restart?

Comment: body { overflow: hidden } ?

Comment: What browser are you testing in? When I view it, there are no scrollbars - the gradient goes to the bottom (even if I resize my window). How many pixels are shown at the bottom? You have `padding` set on `#bubbles`...that may be causing it. Hard to tell since I'm not seeing what you are.

Comment: @disinfor chrome, yes there are no scroll-able bar on the side but if you use mouse scroll downwards you can see it or hitting page down will do it too i think.

Comment: As suspected, it's the `padding` on `#bubbles`. Remove the padding and retest it.

Comment: @disinfor that fixed it!  thank you!  Do you know if its going to break if my page gets longer than the screen length?

Comment: It shouldn't break it because your gradient is set for the `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can figure out the problems like this by using browser inspect element
by the way, to fix this:

Remove `#bubbles` `padding:100px 0`

**OR**

Add `overflow:hidden` to the `#container`

Comment: i've never heard of that, is it a browser plugin?

Comment: if  you are using Google Chrome or Opera, they have a built in addon which you can inspect elements with. but in Firefox, you need to install 'Firebug'. although it has a built in inspector, firebug is way better in my idea .. press f12, or right click on an element and select "inpsect element" or something like this